# SQL DB Migration Recommendations --- Updating database models...can I copy the old records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, merge, database-migration

Say i wanted to update my ASP.NET MVC website. All the data for different view are stored on two SQL dbs, one for roles and membership and one for content. If a table in a db is based off a certain model and I modify that model how can I merge the data from the old model to the new one? Preferably automatically.

I am currently using DropAndCreateIfModelChanges. I understand I will most likely need to copy the db and have say a production db and a dev db that will handle all model changes. The dev db in turn must be copied to the production.

Or in SQL mgmt can I manually add the new columns in SQL mgmt and not drop the DB with its data? That would work perfectly too.

Thank in advance...might not get back to read tonight...

EDIT: So with the info provided below can anyone recommend a tool for db migration
Using ASP.NET 4, IIS 7.5, and SQL 2008 R2. Which are easiest to integrate, which and simple and which are more advanced?

Comment: really nothing overnight....aww shucks!

Comment: It's not clear what is being asked here, but I guess that you want an automated way to deploy your changes in the DB schema. This is called Migrations, and I use DbUp http://www.paulstovell.com/dbup to do it, but the are several solutions to the same problem.

Comment: Thanks that's the idea I was looking for. Edited the question so you can answer, if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use and recommend [DbUp](http://www.paulstovell.com/dbup), because it's simple and script based, but the are several other migrations tools like:

- [SubSonic Migrations](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2010/03/15/subsonic-migrations-without-subsonic)
- [RikMigrations](http://www.rikware.com/page/RikMigrations.aspx)
- [Migrator.Net](http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/)
- [MachineMigrations](http://blog.eleutian.com/2008/04/25/AFirstLookAtMachineMigrations.aspx)

Comment: OctopusDeploy seems to endorse DbUp: http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/SQL+Server+databases#SQLServerdatabases-DbUp

Comment: @yzorg: Paul Stovell, DbUp's creator, it's also the OctopusDeploy creator